# Program loops constantly

Tags: java

From user input. Then it will display that many elements in an array of random integers from 1 to 500. Then from the printed array, it needs to count how many times an increase occurs. Just as an example, if the array is 213, 230, 130, 400, then the number of increases is suppose to be 2 since in that array an increase occurred twice, 213 to 230, and then 130 to 400. However, the program doesn't seem to know when to stop or even know what to loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Spooky {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter integer n, greater than 0: ");
            n = kbd.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);
        System.out.println();

        int[] arr = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Array on one line: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        int count2 = 0;
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    System.out.println(count2);
                    count2++;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing only pairs? What is the counter value for this: `100, 200, 300`? 1 because is "one sequence" or "2" becaue there are 2 pairs (with increasing values)?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Don't define variables you will not use

```
int sum = 0;
```

2 - Try to clean your code, seperate between its blocks so you can understand it better.

3 - It seems clearly that you are still a beginner in Java and it's fine. I recommend you learn more and focus on actually understanding the concepts rather than getting the result. You have to understand what you are doing. You said "However, the program doesn't seem to know when to stop or even know what to loop.", but for me it is not the case.

The two for loops in your code does not find when an increase occurs. You loop twice, and your code will increment the number 'count2' more than it should.

Here is an exemple:

```
172 119 311 237
```

When I tested your code, it gave me 4 which is wrong obviously. You have actually 1 increase.

For the better solution, you can do like this:

```
   int count = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {

               if(arr[i]<arr[i+1]) {
                   count++;
               }

   }

   System.out.println("Number of times subsequent value increases: "+count);
```